# Some mediainfo output is being cut when echoing to file in bash OS X

Tags: macos, bash, csv, mediainfo

If I use the following terminal command:

```
Mediainfo --Language=raw --Full '--Inform=General;%FileSize_String4%' '/Volumes/New Volume//FILM/test.avi'
```

I receive this output, which is what I want:

```
701.5 MiB
```

When I run this bash script in OS X:

```
find "$1" -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.AVI"| (

while IFS= read -r file; do

    vsize=($(Mediainfo --Language=raw --Full --Inform=General\;\%FileSize_String4\% "$file"))
    echo "$file","$vsize" >> /Users/me/fileaudit.csv 
done
)
```

I receive this output (the MiB/Gib etc is stripped):

```
701.5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the outer parentheses... `vsize=$(...)`. You are putting the value in an array as it stands.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks! can you leave it as an answer so I can give you the rep?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I'll be near a proper computer later to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove the outer parentheses where you assign the value to your variable `size`, so it looks like this:

```
vsize=$(Mediainfo --Language=raw --Full --Inform=General\;\%FileSize_String4\% "$file")
```

By the way, you can also get the file size in bytes of a file on OSX with:

```
stat -f "%z" someFile
```